# Quoting in sed execution from bash script

Tags: bash, escaping, double-quotes, quoting, single-quotes

I'm trying to convert one sed command to bash execution, however have hit problem that I can not identify with quoting or variables expansion.

The **working command** directly from console:

```
BASH> diff vault-config.rb vault-config.rb.backup
BASH> sed -n -r -i '/^.*vault_config.*resource.*$/{x;s/\n//p;x;p;s/.*//;h};//!H;${x;s/.*/# Insert File_109 vault for node n109\n$vault_config['"'"'resource'"'"']['"'"'File_109'"'"'] = '"'"'\/tmp\/File_109.json'"'"'\0/p}' "/tmp/vault-config.rb"
BASH> diff vault-config.rb vault-config.rb.backup
208,209d207
< # Insert File_109 vault for node n109
< $vault_config['resource']['File_109'] = '/tmp/File_109.json'
```

The **NON WORKING** attempt to translate to bash script (with some modularity)

```
BASH> NODE="n109"
BASH> VAULT_ID="File_109"
BASH> VAULT_FILE="/tmp/File_109.json"
BASH> VAULT_RESOURCE="\$vault_config['resource']['File_109'] = '/tmp/File_109.json'"
BASH> VAULT_CONFIG_FILE="/tmp/vault-config.rb"

BASH> echo "DEBUG: NODE ${NODE}"
DEBUG: NODE n109
BASH> echo "DEBUG: VAULT_ID ${VAULT_ID}"
DEBUG: VAULT_ID File_109
BASH> echo "DEBUG: VAULT_FILE ${VAULT_FILE}"
DEBUG: VAULT_FILE /tmp/File_109.json
BASH> echo "DEBUG: VAULT RESOURCE ${VAULT_RESOURCE}"
DEBUG: VAULT RESOURCE $vault_config['resource']['File_109'] = '/tmp/File_109.json'
BASH> echo "DEBUG: VAULT_CONFIG_FILE ${VAULT_CONFIG_FILE//"/"/\/}"
DEBUG: VAULT_CONFIG_FILE \/tmp\/vault-config.rb

BASH> args=("-n" "-r" "-i" "'/^.*vault_config.*resource.*\$/{x;s/\\n//p;x;p;s/.*//;h};//!H;\${x;s/.*/#This is automated insert of key ${VAULT_ID} vault for node ${NODE}\\n${VAULT_RESOURCE}\\0/p}'" "${VAULT_CONFIG_FILE//"/"/\/}")
-bash: !H: event not found
BASH> #sed "${args[0]}" # <-- commented because previous command is failing
```

Result is `-bash: !H: event not found` after the assignment to args. I tried various forms of escape in the args element and also in the variable `VAULT_RESOURCE` as I believe the args might not like the single quotes inside.

When I escape the `!` to `\!` the args command stops failing, however sed is failing and it seems that args includes only first 3 arguments in this case.

My conclusion after already spending several hours with this command is that the error I'm getting is not related to the real error and there is something in the background as per documentation `!` does not needs to be escaped within double quotes, but reality is different

```
BASH> TEST="Test string !H"
-bash: !H": event not found
BASH> TEST="Test string \!H"
BASH> echo $TEST
Test string \!H
```

What works as workaround is to put this one command to temporary .sh script and call this script, but I do not like it.

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Putting the commands in an array might not be the best approach; regardless of that escaping the quotes is usually the standard way to handle it (eg. `"\'...\'"`)

Comment: Tried also following options: Direct execution / Eval execution / One string execution and none of them worked. The only working solution is to create tmp file with sed command, chmod to 700 and execute, but it is not according to best practices and can be security risk having file in /tmp with these rights.

Comment: `set +H` (aka `histexpand`) should switch off history ! expansion, but that is normally switched off for scripts by default.